# File.ReadLines returns null char after each other char

Tags: c#, .net, file, file.readalllines

I am trying to read all lines from the file, however I am getting some unexpected results, code:

```
var readLines = File.ReadLines(file);

foreach (var line in readLines)
{
    //line = "T\0e\0s\0t\0"
}
```

File contents:

> Test

If I will do `line.Replace("\0", "")` then it works fine however I would like to understand why this is happening and how I can get correct value from the file using ReadLines?

Comment: Looks like file encoding to me, what encoding is the file using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file seems to be encoded in UTF-16. Specify the encoding in the second parameter to `ReadLines()`

```
var readLines = File.ReadLines(file, Encoding.Unicode);
```

---

`File.ReadLines()` without the second parameter assumes UTF-8 as the encoding of the file. UTF-16 files use two bytes to encode a character (latin characters use the first one in UTF-16, and only one byte in UTF-8). So to UTF-8, in your text every other character is `\0`.

Comment: That is it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know why it results into this odd behaviour?

Comment: It's not "odd behaviour"; whoever/whatever wrote that file made it save the characters like that.